# Qt Determine if application is launched from Qt Creator?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

How can I from within my code determine if my application is started from Qt Creator (either by "F5" or "Ctrl + R")?

The reason why I want to know this is because I want to create my own debug message handler ( using qInstallMessageHandler()) **only** when the application is launched from the executable directly. Since Qt allows only one message handler, I don't want to create my own when launching from Qt Creator, or else I can't see the debug messages in Qt Creators own debug console.

Comment: The debug message handler has nothing to do with running the application in debug vs release mode.  The short answer is that you shouldn't be concerned about it.  Just use qDebug for printing information out to the console.  If you want everything to go out to std::cout or std::cerr then you should at that point overload the message handler using qInstallMessageHandler.  On windows there are some slight differences between a console application's output and a GUI application's output but you can google that up easily.

Comment: I'm not talking about debug vs release. What I mean is that when the user run my application outside of QtCreator, I want the messages that usually show in QtCreator's debug console to show in a textbox in my own application's gui instead (since the user will not have QtCreator open).

Comment: qInstallMessageHandler and write to your textbox

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is an easy way to detect that.
You could add a command line argument to the run settings in QtCreator though, and check for that at runtime.

Comment: Seems this is the best solution so far. I would have thought there was a more standard way of detecting this. But this is the closest I can get.

Answer (score 3):

I have two possible solutions:

1. check the names of parent process (or parent of parent)

   there are multiple ways to do this: under Posix (mingw, linux etc..) you have getppid(). Under Windows you can check the namehave the [Psapi](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682629%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or other process handling functions. I have done this for other purposes in the past and it works reliably as long as the process names do not change. Alternatively you could check for the window names. Unfortunately none of these solutions are "Qt-Native".
2. supply a commandline argument only when started from Qt creator

   If you use a library to scan commanline arguments this is probably the simplest solution. I usually use Boost Program Options (Google there). You could create a commandline argument like "--console-log" which specifies to put the logging output to the console. To set that option from within Qt Creator is documented [here.](http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.6/creator-run-settings.html) This is probably the most "Qt-Native" solution. If you use Qt functions to parse the commandline, it is 100% Qt.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [IsDebuggerPresent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680345.aspx) or use only QDebug and check debug messages with [debugview](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647) outside QT Creator.

Comment: Thanks, but IsDebuggerPresent does not return true when launching the application from within QtCreator (ctrl + r), without debugging (F5).
I thought there would be some Qt command to detect this, but seems there's no easy way..

Answer (score 0):

You should google qInstallMessageHandler for more information.

But here goes the definitions:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtWidgets>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
  ~MainWindow();

  static void myMessageHandler(QtMsgType type, const QMessageLogContext &context, const QString &msg)
  {
    // If you're running lots of threads you'll need to do some research to
    // determine if you need to make this synchronized (i.e. locked)
    if(staticTextEdit) {
      staticTextEdit->appendPlainText(msg + "\n");
    }
  }

private slots:
  void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
  // There's lots of different ways to do this ... this was the quickest way for me.
  static QPlainTextEdit* staticTextEdit;
  Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Here are the declarations:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

QPlainTextEdit* MainWindow::staticTextEdit = NULL;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
  QMainWindow(parent),
  ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
  ui->setupUi(this);
  staticTextEdit = ui->plainTextEdit;
  qInstallMessageHandler(MainWindow::myMessageHandler);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
  delete ui;
}

// I'm using QtCreator to help create my slots.  =).
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
  qDebug() << "CLICKED";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already know how to use the message handler. My question was **how I know when to use my custom message handler (I don't want it when launching the application from QtCreator)**.

Comment: When the application is compiled, there's a DEBUG macro that is passed to it.  You can toggle on that (i.e. Code).  Here of course, I assume that you're not using the "debug" version outside of the IDE.  From windows, You'd probably want to toggle on _DEBUG - [check here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Problem is that I can run release (i.e. DEBUG not set) when running the application from QtCreator.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a manual solution.

Define a macro in your .pro file....

```
# To turn on remove the comment marker '#'
#    isEmpty(LAUNCH_FROM_IDE):LAUNCH_FROM_IDE = 1
    !isEmpty(LAUNCH_FROM_IDE) {
            DEFINES += APP_LAUNCH_FROM_IDE
    }
```

And use in your header/source as needed...

```
#ifdef APP_LAUNCH_FROM_IDE
...
#endif
```

That's all

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this applies to the PC, but under OSX, when Qt Creator launches the application, it does it from the development build path; you can get the current launch path with:

```
QString expath = QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath();
```

Get that, dump it via `qDebug()`, and see where you're running from when launched from Qt. As long as that's not the location you run the application from when you're not launching it from within Qt, this should work.

I get this from the qDebug() when building and running in release mode from within Qt Creator:

```
"/Users/fyngyrz/build-iToolBox-Desktop_Qt_5_8_0_clang_64bit-Release/iToolBox.app/Contents/MacOS/iToolBox"
```

So for me, when building my app `iToolBox` I do the detection like this:

```
if (expath.indexOf("build-iToolBox-Desktop") != -1) // if we're running from inside Qt
{
}
else // we're not running from inside qt
{
}
```

## Note1:

The release and build paths for Qt builds are different by default; so if you need this to work in both release and debug circumstances, you might have to do two checks of the path instead of one, depending on just what you're searching for.

## Note 2:

If you incorporate this approach into your application, and the code will remain intact in the release build, be sure not to including anything in your search string that would incorporate any information you don't want to share, such as your real name which could be part of the path under some operating systems, depending on how you set up your user account.